# LinkedIn API throwing 'No virtual resource found' error with 404 code while creating a campaign group . How to solve it?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am facing issue while Create a Campaign Group in LinkedIn. API giving `No virtual resource found` error with `404` error code. I have created test ads account and using same for creating campaign.

I want to create campaign. Account user have ACCOUNT_MANAGER and ACCOUNT_BILLING_ADMIN role.